# Edição na ListView

Tags: xml, android-layout

Criei um xml separado para mexer melhor com o ListView.. só que não estou conseguindo relacionar o id dele no meu onCreate

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
        android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/corList"
        tools:targetApi="ice_cream_sandwich"
        android:paddingRight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft" />


</LinearLayout>
```

esse xml esta no /res/layout/resultado_modificado.xml

Java:

```
package com.allsport.miyonic.allsport;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

        import Base.DbHelper;
        import Base.Esporte;

        import static android.os.FileObserver.DELETE;

public class ResultSimples extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView lista;
    private Button apagar;
    public TextView txt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result_simples);

        lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListaTimes);
        apagar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btndeletar);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1); 
        apagar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DbHelper dd = new DbHelper(ResultSimples.this);
                dd.delete(); // É necessário passar o parâmetro
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        DbHelper dbhe = new DbHelper(this);
        List<Esporte> listaResultPartida = dbhe.selectTodosResult();

        ArrayAdapter<Esporte> adp = new ArrayAdapter<Esporte>(this, R.layout.resultado_modificado, listaResultPartida);

        lista.setAdapter(adp);
    }
}
```

Obrigado...

Comment: Nathan, você teria que postar o xml do item do `Adapter` que está passando para o ListView. Não tem como alterar a cor do item diretamente do `ListView`.

Comment: Então @Wakim como que funciona... tentei olhar na internet e não consegui entender... parece que o `Adapter` necessita de um `TextView` ou algo desse tipo.... como que funciona?

Comment: Então Nathan, recomendo que dê uma olhada nesse link: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews. Tem uma documentação bem detalhada sobre a customização do `ListView`.

Comment: @Wakim, preciso criar um xml separado com o textview e depois no java eu chamo ele como se fosse no `simple_list_item_1` é isso né?

Comment: Isso exato, como o `simple_list_item_1` é do framework, você não consegue alterar o xml. Existem duas alternativas, ou você cria um Adapter próprio e altera a cor programaticamente quando a `View` for criada, ou cria um xml semelhante e altera a cor no xml. Eu recomendo a segunda abordagem, fica mais claro e da menos trabalho.

Comment: Criei um xml, e coloquei no java na parte do `onResume` essa linha   `ArrayAdapter<Esporte> adp = new ArrayAdapter<Esporte>(this, R.layout.resultado_modificado, listaResultPartida);` e esta me apresentando esse erro no LogCat **java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView** só que no onCreate não estou conseguindo relacionar ele, chamando o `ID` - criei um private em cima `(private TextView txt;)` e dentro onCreate `txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);` e não está indo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47886/discussion-between-nathan-and-wakim).

Answer (score 1):

Consegui com ajuda do @Wakim, precisei passar o id dentro do construtor do Adpter

dessa forma:

```
@Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        DbHelper dbhe = new DbHelper(this);
        List<Esporte> listaResultPartida = dbhe.selectTodosResult();
        ArrayAdapter<Esporte> adp = new ArrayAdapter<Esporte>(this, R.layout.resultado_modificado, android.R.id.text1, listaResultPartida);

        lista.setAdapter(adp);
    }
}
```